# Is it possible to evaluate and compile a block of JS with Webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have an object that I'm creating with an IIFE in order to keep it more manageable. However, the values are static and the object should always be the same. So, to avoid unnecessary processing, I'd like for the bundled file to contain the actual object rather than the function expression. Is this possible? If not, is there a better way I could be doing this?

#### Source JS:

```
const keyMap = (function () {
    const keys = {
        tab: 9,
        up: 38,
        down: 40,
        left: 37,
        right: 39,
        enter: 13,
        space: 32,
        ' ': 32,
        shift: 16,
        ctrl: 17,
        alt: 18,
        win: 91,
        backspace: 8,
        capsLock: 20,
        ',': 188,
        '.': 190,
        '/': 191,
        '\\': 220,
        esc: 27
    };

    const alph = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

    for (let i = 0; i < alph.length; i++) {
        keys[alph[i]] = i + 97;
        keys[alph[i].toUpperCase()] = i + 65;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        keys[i] = i + 48;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
        keys[`pad${i}`] = i + 96;
    }

    return keys;
})();
```

#### Expected Result:

```
const keyMap = {tab: 9, up: 38, ..., a: 97, b:98, ... }
```

Comment: Why? I dont think that the IIFE will impact perofmance in any way.

Comment: Sure, I guess this example doesn't really make much of a difference, but I was mostly just curious if something like this was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the output from the computation in the IIFE block as the keyMap object

```
const keyMap = {
  0: 48,
  1: 49,
  2: 50,
  3: 51,
  4: 52,
  5: 53,
  6: 54,
  7: 55,
  8: 56,
  9: 57,
  tab: 9,
  up: 38,
  down: 40,
  left: 37,
  right: 39,
  enter: 13,
  space: 32,
  '': 32,
  shift: 16,
  ctrl: 17,
  alt: 18,
  win: 91,
  backspace: 8,
  capsLock: 20,
  ',': 188,
  '.': 190,
  '/': 191,
  '\\': 220,
  esc: 27,
  a: 97,
  A: 65,
  b: 98,
  B: 66,
  c: 99,
  C: 67,
  d: 100,
  D: 68,
  e: 101,
  E: 69,
  f: 102,
  F: 70,
  g: 103,
  G: 71,
  h: 104,
  H: 72,
  i: 105,
  I: 73,
  j: 106,
  J: 74,
  k: 107,
  K: 75,
  l: 108,
  L: 76,
  m: 109,
  M: 77,
  n: 110,
  N: 78,
  o: 111,
  O: 79,
  p: 112,
  P: 80,
  q: 113,
  Q: 81,
  r: 114,
  R: 82,
  s: 115,
  S: 83,
  t: 116,
  T: 84,
  u: 117,
  U: 85,
  v: 118,
  V: 86,
  w: 119,
  W: 87,
  x: 120,
  X: 88,
  y: 121,
  Y: 89,
  z: 122,
  Z: 90,
  pad0: 96,
  pad1: 97,
  pad2: 98,
  pad3: 99,
  pad4: 100,
  pad5: 101,
  pad6: 102,
  pad7: 103,
  pad8: 104,
  pad9: 105,
};
```

Comment: I'd rather avoid hardcoding it in case something needs to change. Especially if I use something like this in a more complex object.

Comment: But you said "However, the values are static and the object should always be the same."

Comment: When the function is executed, the value of `keyMap` will be an object in the engine. I don't see a compelling reason to have the Webpack store the result object rather than the function. If it's necessary that it is an object when it's compiled, hardcoding is acceptable in this case IMO.

Comment: I meant that as in the resulting object would not change between builds as long as that the IIFE is not touched. But I'd like to keep it more manageable in case something _does_ need to change. I guess it just makes more sense to me to have it be "hardcoded" in the bundled file while still making modifications easy.

Comment: In that case, your approach seems fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a json file instead of an object made form an iife. Just because it's a constant and seems like your bundle has a dependency on it.
And then I would import/require the json in the beginning of my entry file and then inject it inside the app function.
And since require/import are processed synchronously, the bundle will import the json before initing the application